# I have a US Refugee Travel Document and am currently studying in the UK for a semester; are there Schengen countries I can travel to without a visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, refugees, us-residents, embassies

I am a US permanent resident and I am currently studying abroad in England with a student short-term visa. I went to apply for a Schengen visa to VFS, but I got told that I would need to go back to the States and apply from them (as you can imagine, I cannot do this because it's costly to return). I did some research and found out that I can enter Belgium without a visa if I have a US Refugee Travel Document, which I do have.

I was wondering if there is a way I can travel to other Schengen countries without a visa. Thanks for your assistance--I appreciate it. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: The link in the previous comment is from 2015 (and some of the links are dead) , so you must check, country for country, based in the list of countries you wish to travel through to see if it still uptodate. Applying for a visa should normally be done in the country of residence (as you did for the UK). Do not be tempted to go to countries where their embassy sites state that you need a visa just because there are no border controls.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I wrote that answer, and to the best of my knowledge nothing has changed. I'll update the links in a bit.

Comment: If your study in the UK began longer than three months before your trip to the Schengen area then you should be able to benefit from an exception to the rule that visa applications must be processed by the consulate with jurisdiction over your place of residence.  I suspect, however, that this is difficult to achieve in practice.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkJohnson and Phoog for your answers, I really appreciate it. I have been in the UK for a month only and plan to travel in March or April. The UK visa I will expire in July, so in 5 months. What do you guys recommend that I do then in order to be able to go to other countries besides the free-visa ones listed on the website?